# Is this quantum mechanical proof of the virial theorem general?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-principle, ground-state, scaling, virial-theorem

I have seen the following proof for the virial theorem in QM using the variational method. It goes like this:

Suppose an exact eigenstate of the system is $\psi(\vec{r})$ and consider a variational state $\psi(a\vec{r})$ (where we will set $a=1$ later but keep it general for now).

The expectation of the potential energy of the state in $d$-dimensions is given by:

$$\langle PE \rangle_{var} = \langle \psi|V(r)|\psi\rangle = \frac{\int d^d\vec{r} |\psi(a\vec{r})|^2 kr^2 }{\int d^d \vec{r} |\psi(a\vec{r})|^2}$$

(using the fact that $\psi(a\vec{r})$ will not be normalised so we must divide by its norm  square in order to normalise the 2 $\psi$'s in the expectation value).

Using a change of variables $\vec{R} = a\vec{r}$ we get:

$$\langle PE \rangle_{var} = a^{-n} \frac{\int d^d\vec{R} |\psi(a\vec{R})|^2 kR^2 }{\int d^d \vec{r} |\psi(a\vec{R})|^2} = a^{-n} \langle PE \rangle_{exact}$$

(where we have seen that the fraction is equal to $\langle PE \rangle_{exact}$ since it's nothing but the usual expectation of potential energy for $\psi(\vec{r})$ but using the symbol $\vec{R}$ instead of $\vec{r}$)

Similarly we can show $\langle KE \rangle_{var} = a^2 \langle KE \rangle_{exact}$.

So $\langle E \rangle_{var} =  a^2 \langle KE \rangle_{exact} + a^{-n} \langle PE \rangle_{exact}$

Therefore differentiating with respect to $a$ to find the optimum value of $a$ which minimises the total energy.

$2a \langle KE \rangle_{exact} -na^{-{n+1}} \langle PE \rangle_{exact} = 0 $

But we know $a=1$ is optimal so:

$\langle KE \rangle_{exact} =  \frac{n}{2} \langle PE \rangle_{exact}$

My question is why we differentiate with respect to a to minimise the total energy and if this really is general.

My only guess is if we actually also assume that $\psi(\vec{r})$ is not just any exact eigenstate but the *ground* state (which is usually what we are concerned with in the variational method anyway), then minimising the total energy is the usual method of finding an approximation for the ground state from some 'guessed' state $\psi(a\vec{r})$. However, in this case, aren't we just showing that the ground state must be consistent with the virial theorem, rather than any energy state?